# Cannot import name 'iterable' from 'matplotlib.cbook'

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, ubuntu, iterable

Recently, I updated to Ubuntu 22. I am using python 3.10.

After installing matplotlib and other required libraries for python, I am trying to plot some graphs.

Everytime I am facing this error while running my code.
I followed all the solutions given in stackoverflow or Google but no luck.

This is the error I am getting:

```
File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/prettyplotlib/_eventplot.py:3, in <module>
      1 __author__ = 'jgosmann'
----> 3 from matplotlib.cbook import iterable
      5 from prettyplotlib.utils import remove_chartjunk, maybe_get_ax
      6 from prettyplotlib.colors import set2

ImportError: cannot import name 'iterable' from 'matplotlib.cbook'
```

When I imported matplotlib, there is no issue.

How can I get rid of this error?
Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Which version of matplotlib are  you using?

Comment: I am using 3.5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone searching for the answer to solve this issue,

then follow the following steps:

step 1) uninstall matplotlib completely

step 2 ) Then install matplotlib : pip3 install -U matplotlib==3.2

Answer (score 0):

From From https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/commit/08dc21b038e43401652fed765288bb669abb8b0c#diff-734998909c4e54bce8138043e769bea5654259de61cc909be9d84b04485cdae9R46, it looks like that this has been removed/deprecated.

Comment suggests using `numpy.iterable()`

So I guess you'd need to change:

```
 from matplotlib.cbook import iterable
```

to

```
 from numpy import iterable
```

Comment: Do you mean by change it to python root file?

Comment: If you can,  otherwise, I think pinging the original author about the required change (depending on matplotlib's version)    You could change it locally until it is fixed upstream.   (one option) or ping the author and wait until they fix it upstream.

Comment: Let me see, if I can. Thanks

Comment: It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'iterable' from 'matplotlib.cbook'
```

go to the cbook directory of the matplotlib package, and edit the `__init__.py` file like this: wherever `cb.iterable()` is written, change it to `np.iterable()`.